# How to allow entry (edit by user) of customtkinter table?

Tags: customtkinter

I've created a table using customtkinter-table. I would like to allow the user to edit entries (cells) of the table but couldn't find a way to do so, the table is static in the GUI.

this is what I tried:

```
self.table = CTkTable(self,  row=5, column=4, values=value)
self.table.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 0), sticky="nw")
```